# What is purpose of Identification number in IPv4 header when DNF flag is set?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-fragmentation

The identification number in the IPv4 header is used in packet fragmentation and re-assembly. If the "Do not fragment" flag is set, does the identification field has any significance?

Addition: Also, I see in Wireshark that whenever the DNF flag is set, Identification number is 0. Is that standardized or implementation dependant?

[Wireshark Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwsSA.png)

Comment: You should be specific. I think you mean the IPv4 header because there is no such field in the IPv6 header, so it is not universal for IP. _[RFC 791, Internet Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)_ explains the Identification field: "_An identifying value assigned by the sender to aid in assembling the fragments of a datagram._" It also explains: "_The internet protocol implements two basic functions:  addressing and fragmentation._" IPv6 does not have in-path fragmentation the way IPv4 does, so it does not have that field. IPv4 is an _experiment_ that IP v6 has replaced.

Comment: "IP" means "IPv4"; IPv4 is not experimental and IPv6 is not really "replacing" v4 (well, maybe it is, but it is happening very slowly!)

Comment: @Andrew, "_IPv4 is not experimental_" Just ask Vint Cerf, the father of IP. IPv4 is an experiment that escaped the lab, and it was never intended for the current Internet. It has some serious problems, not the least of which is the lack of addressing that forces it to now break its original paradigm of unique addressing for every interface. Fragmentation also proved a problem. IPv6 learned the lessons of the IPv4 mistakes, removed bad features improved other features, and added new features. _[Google
 IPv6 Adoption](https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html)_

Comment: I agree it has problems and was not intended for production, but it now clearly is very widely deployed in production (not as an experiment).

Comment: @RonMaupin, Yes, I am referring to the IPv4 protocol. I have edited the question.